# mongodb insertOne method difficulties

Tags: java, json, mongodb, coldfusion, railo

I'm trying to use the `insertOne` method in order to insert a document into a collection named 'people'. I have tried several methods to create the json,  but all of them failed with a different error message. I code in ColdFusion (Railo) and am using the java driver 3.2.2.

For instance, the following syntax :

```
<cfset people.insertOne( { item: "card", qty: 15 } )>
```

generates the following errors:

```
    railo.runtime.type.StructImpl cannot be cast to org.bson.Document
```

the following syntax:

```
<cffunction name="m" returntype="any">
<cfargument name="value" type="any">
<cfif IsJSON(arguments.value)>
    <cfset local.retrun = CreateObject("java","com.mongodb.util.JSON").parse(arguments.value)>
<cfelse>
    <cfset local.retrun = CreateObject("java","com.mongodb.util.JSON").parse( SerializeJSON(arguments.value) )>     
</cfif>
<cfreturn local.retrun>
```

```
<cfset doc = {
            "Name"  = "Marc",
            "Spouse"= "Heather",
            "Fruit" = "Mango",
            "Kids"  = [
                {"Name"="Alexis", "Age"=7, "Hair"="blonde", "Description"="crazy" },
                {"Name"="Sidney", "Age"=2, "Hair"="dirty blonde", "Description"="ornery" }
            ],
            "Bike" = "Felt",
            "LoveSQL" = true,
            "TS" = now(),
            "Counter" = 1
        }>
<cfset doc  = SerializeJSON(doc)>
<cfset doc  = m(doc)>
<cfset people.insertOne( doc )>
```

generates the following error:

```
    com.mongodb.BasicDBObject cannot be cast to org.bson.Document
```

How can I cast the json in order to insert the document into the collection?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/marcesher/cfmongodb or https://github.com/henrylearn2rock/MongoCFC ?

Comment: (Edit) Henry makes a fair point about trying out an existing implementation.  *RE: generates the following error* A) What is the complete stack trace message? The "caused by" section is usually at the bottom. B) How are you loading the jars, via application level setting, jars added to the CF class path, etctera...?